# What methods are needed to create custom Applicative Functor to use with scalaz |@|

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, applicative

I would like to be able to do use scalaz's |@| on my own applicative functor.

Example:
`val spread: Source[Yield] = (y2 |@| y1)(_ - _)`

This is my class

```
sealed abstract class Source[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Source[B] 
  def unit[A](a: A): Source[A]
  def pureList[A](la: List[A]): Source[A]
  def zero[A]: Source[A]
  def map2[A, B, C](as: Source[A], bs: Source[B], f: (A, B) => C): Source[C]
}
```

I'm certain I have to implement `map` because it's a functor.
An applicative can be implemented in various ways: for example using `apply()` and `unit()` or `map2()` and `unit()`.

Do I need `ap` and `pure` as well?

As you can see I'm not sure what is needed.

Comment: Note that for your example you only need `Apply` not `Applicative`.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz I don't understand; do you mean I don't need method `apply` but I need method `applicative`? Or do you mean I should call it an Apply functor instead of Applicative functor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
implicit val mya = new Applicative[Source] {}
```

Let the compiler answer that question for you:

```
object creation impossible, since:
it has 2 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from <$anon: scalaz.Applicative[Source]>, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  // Members declared in scalaz.Applicative
  def point[A](a: => A): Source[A] = ???

  // Members declared in scalaz.Apply
  def ap[A, B](fa: => Source[A])(f: => Source[A => B]): Source[B] = ???
```